# Are conditions in an EVALUATE TRUE block evaluated in the same order they're listed?

Tags: cobol

If I evaluate independent variables in the same EVALUATE TRUE block, are they evaluated in the order they are listed?

E.g., if it's "COLD" and "SUNNY", would I ever "BRING SUNGLASSES?" Or would I just "WEAR SWEATER" and exit the block?

```
 EVALUATE TRUE
  WHEN COLD
     WEAR SWEATER
  WHEN SUNNY
     BRING SUNGLASSES
 END-EVALUATE
```

Comment: check out http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Cobol/comp.lang.cobol/2007-08/msg00523.html for a detailed answer using another weather related "whether" problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many other languages, we often need to insert break statement (or similar) to each selection, so that it does not fall through. However that’s not the case in COBOL evaluate, COBOL evaluate ends when one of those selections satisfies (or none).

Comment: And so, yes. It evaluates the clauses in the order that you code them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are evaluated in the order they are listed. Once it meets the condition of one of the `WHEN` statements it breaks out of the code and goes to the `END-EVALUATE`